# Force openlayers to not use browser cache for tiles refresh

Tags: openlayers-2, tiles, cache

I use OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ to display tiles from TileStache server without using the cache option of the server. However, I notice that the tiles stay in cache (probably the browser cache) until the whole page is refreshed with Ctrl-F5.

If I want to redraw the XYZ layer, it does not works because the map use the browser cache. Is there a way to force the map to not use that cache? So could refresh the layer by asking fresh tiles from the server.

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',
          { projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
            numZoomLevels: 20 });

var tiledLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ('TMS',
                "{{ tmsURL }}1.0/layer/{{ shapefile.id }}/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?"+ new Date().getTime());

map.addLayer(tiledLayer);
tiledLayer.redraw(true); //does not make new GET requests to the server
```

Comment: You have to post your code. But the standard method for forcing a refresh is adding a current time as a get parameter (ie ?time=1408642981 ). The server will ignore the parameter as it doesn't know it but the browser won't use local cache.

Comment: that does not works!

Comment: It does work, it does exactly what you asked for, omits the browser cache. You got what you asked for before I could take a look on your code, that's no reason to get rude.

Comment: I dont want to be rude :P you'r idea was a good one, but for a reason I dont understand, it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jakub Kania was correct in his comment that the date/time have to be added to the url to make it different from the url of tiles in the cache. You have to subclass OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ for that:

```
OpenLayers.Layer.CustomXYZ = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ, {
  getURL: function () {
    var url = OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ.prototype.getURL.apply(this, arguments);
    return url + '?time='+ new Date().getTime();
  }
});

var tiledLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.CustomXYZ('TMS',
                "{{ tmsURL }}1.0/layer/{{ shapefile.id }}/${z}/${x}/${y}.png");

tiledLayer.redraw(true);
```

Comment: That's interesting. Once I saw the code I was gonna suggest to add a new layer, wait for it to load and remove the old one. Didn't thought you can just hack the function.